# Magento 1.9 module name conflict with different package

Tags: magento-1.9

> I have created an extension with "Mypackage_Wishlist". When I tried to
>   override controller it conflicts with "Mage_Wishlist". It shows blank
>   pages on my account -> My wishlist page.
>
> Can we remove conflicts with same module name with different package
>   name?

Answer (score 1):

> How do I identify extension conflicts? There is a great extension(!)
>   that will go through all your extensions looking for conflicts. This
>   can be found here. :-
>   https://github.com/juito/module-conflict-detector
>
> WebShopApps offer a modified version of this which works on Enterprise
>   editions of Magento – we produced for a customer so thought may as
>   well release. More info here.
>
> For theme conflicts there isn't a tool I know of to detect these, it
>   comes down to good old concentration!
>
> **How do I resolve conflicts? You have 3 choices for resolving
>   conflicts:**
>
> Merge the code from one conflicting file into another and switch off
>   the rewrite config.xml in one Switch off the rewrite in one config.xml
>   and then make the conflicting extension PHP file extend the other
>   extension Use the  capability to make one extension depend on
>   another. They will then rewrite in that order Which one you choose
>   really does depend on how far you need to go. More often than not even
>   though a class may conflict the actual methods within may not. In this
>   scenario, I’d go for option 3. If you have conflicting methods within
>   classes then option 1 or 2 are applicable.
>
> EXAMPLE OF OPTION 2 So originally where you may have had something
>   like:
>
> class A_Extension_Model_Type_Onepage extends
>   Mage_Checkout_Model_Type_Onepage You would change it to:
>
> class A_Extension_Model_Type_Onepage extends
>   B_Extension_Model_Type_Onepage Once you have done this you need to
>   change extension B config.xml file commenting out the conflicting
>   “” blocks that are now inheriting from A.
>
> EXAMPLE OF OPTION 3 Let’s say you have 2 extensions Foo_A and Foo_B.
>   In the module for file Foo_B (under app/etc/modules) you would add the
>   following:
>
> Now Magento will load the extensions in this order.
>   So in effect, the Foo_B class will be loaded first, then Foo_A, then
>   base Magento.

Comment: Hi Umesh, Thanks for quick answer. your answer is helpful. Just wanted to check if i use "<helpers>
      <wishlist>
        <class>MyPackage_Wishlist_Helper</class>
      </wishlist>
    </helpers>"
in my config.xml of extension.
it gives error.

Answer (score 1):

To Solve your issue you have two possible solutions

1. Module `Mypackage_Wishlist` rewrite module `Mage_Wishlist`
2. Register the module `Mypackage_Wishlist` frontname/helper layer with a different identifier : (eg: `<b_wishlist>`)

Comment: Hi piyush, Just try to create Mypackage_wishlist from module creator and try to rewrite wishlist controller , layout xml file and create helper. you will get en error.

Comment: if you want to use helper with same name `wishlist` you need to rewrite the `Mage_Wishlist` helper or change the helper identifier in `config.xml`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

> app/etc/modules/Mypackage_Wishlist.xml

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <Mypackage_Wishlist>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
            <depends>
                <Mage_Wishlist/>
            </depends>
        </Mypackage_Wishlist>
    </modules>
</config>
```

Comment: Try to create data helper class with in "Mypackage_Wishlist" in config.xml. you will get an error